# Does the session garbage collector runs even if session is not idle?

Tags: php

I set in php.ini :

```
session.gc_probability = 100
session.gc_divisor     = 100
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1040
```

So it is sure the session garbage collector will run after 1040 seconds. But what I want to know is that : does this session garbage collector run even if the user is not idle after creating a session ?

Answer (score 1):

Every time user accessing the application the session file age will be reset to zero. So it will live at least next 1040 seconds.

Comment: But I want to clear database session data if they are considered old. So what to do ?